# How to use data written to page by jQuery available for other actions?

Tags: jquery

On a certain event, I have data written to the page using `html()`. I want to use that data right away for other things. For example (keeping this as simple as possible):

```
$('.linkclass').click(function() {

  $('#divid').html('<a id="mylink" href="#somelink">Click me</a>');

});
```

On the page:

```
<a class="linkclass">Random link</a>
<div id="divid"> </div>
```

This works fine. However, trying to work with the data that was written to `#divid` doesn't:

```
$('.linkclass').click(function() {

  $('#divid').html('<a id="mylink" href="#somelink">Click me</a>');
  $('#mylink').trigger("click"); // doesn't work if not originally on page

});
```

So, how can I work with the data that was written to `#divid`?

Comment: UPDATE: Edited due to mistake in original code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround for your issue could be

```
$('.linkclass').click(function() {

  $('#divid').html('<a id="mylink" href="#helo">Click me</a>');
  var url = $('#mylink').attr('href');
  window.location = url; 

});
```

You can test it by setting href to http://www.google.com for example

Comment: Sorry, that was a mis-type on my part. Code updated.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work, because you dont have an element with id "somelink".

Rewrite this:

```
$('#divid').html('<a href="#somelink">Click me</a>');
```

into this

```
$('#divid').html('<a href="#somelink" id="somelink">Click me</a>');
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a mis-type on my part. Code updated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can trigger a click on an HTML `<a>` tag in order to trigger the default behavior of the element (go to another page). "[Click jacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking)" wouldn't exist if we could do something like that.

But you sure can set a `click` event listener on this element, then do what you want to :

```
$(document).on("click", '#somelink', function() {
  window.location.replace('https://www.google.com');
});

$('.linkclass').click(function() {
  $('#divid').html('<a id="somelink">Click me</a>');
  $('#somelink').trigger("click");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this programmatically, [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/birdyinc/Zf6a5/8/) (jsFiddle):

```
$('.linkclass').click(function() {

var $newlink1 = $("<a id='new-link-1'/>")
.attr('href','#3')
.html("clicky")
.click(alert('clicked!')); //debug

$("#divid").append($newlink1);

});
```

Somehow I think the `<a>` isn't being added to the dom in time for jQuery to reference it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.linkclass').click(function () {
    $('#divid').html('<a id="mylink" href="#somelink">Click me</a>');
    $('#mylink')[0].click();
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/4cVSV/